# How to rotate markups along with PDF on Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a PDF drawing already loaded into Forge Viewer and have some markups on it. When PDF be rotated by using camera the markups are not keep the initial position, angle... but it go away from the Viewer. Is it possible to keep markups rotate along with the PDF. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to keep track of the world coordinates between translation (movement of PDF) and convert them back to client/viewport coordinates to maintain their relative positions within the canvas - you can subscribe to the `CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT` to react to user navigation and move the markups accordingly:

```
//once the markups are created
const originalWorldPos = viewer.clientToWorld(pos.x,pos.y)

viewer.addEventListner(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, ()=>{
   let newViewPortPos = viewer.worldToClient(originalWorldPos)
   //move markups to new position here ...
})
```